# Программа для вывода распознанных чисел в график в реальном времени

Tags: распознавание

Есть программа в которой я в реальном времени вижу изменение интересующих меня числовых значений (например напряжение бортовой сети автомобиля)(т.е. значение фактически идёт как число, а не картинка). Мне нужна программа которая могла бы распознать это значение и вывести в график(параметр по времени) в реальном времени. Подскажите, пожалуйста, такую программу?

"откуда идет число из программы ?"
программа считывает данные автомобиля и выводит их на экран как числа с примерным обновлением 2 раза в секунду.
"может эта программа имеет api и может куда-то число выдавать ?"
возможно только видеть эти значение, вывода данных в файл или ещё куда-либо кроме как на экран - нет.

извините, что не по теме, просто уже голову сломал пытаясь что-то такое найти, потом увидел этот сайт и показалось что тут толковые люди смогут хотябы подсказать направление.
еще раз извините.

"Если вы их видите, то они как-то поступают на устройство отображения и их можно считать"
специальный адаптер считывает с кан-шины автомобиля необходимые значения, преобразует в другой формат(протокол) и пересылает через USB шнурок на компьютер, в компьютере программа расшифровывает данные и выводит их на экран. 
Мне кажется мы немного о разном говорим.
меня интересует как распознать уже имеющиеся данные с одновременным переводом в график, т.е. задать область на экране которую компьютер, допустим 2 раза в секунду распознает и выведет в график.

Comment: откуда идет число из программы ? может эта программа имеет api и может куда-то число выдавать ? вы действительно хотите его из картинки распознавать  ? 

вообще вопрос не по теме, тут люди задают вопросы, когда не могут решить что-то конкретное в программировании (т.е. вот пишут они программу, а какая-то мелочь не получается, они и спрашивают "а почему?"), а поиск программ или поиск тех кто напишет программы по тз. в другом каком-то месте делают.

Comment: >> возможно только видеть эти значение

Если вы их видите, то они как-то поступают на устройство отображения и их можно считать.
Без подробностей более ценных комментариев вы не получите.